# Multilevel login system in Python randomly rejecting attempts

Tags: python

I wrote this multilevel login system in Python. When I logged in with the data in the first row, it worked just fine, but when I tried the second data line, I couldn't log in.

This is how the login data looks like (stored in a `.txt` file):

```
1|Farhan|admin|admin|Administrator
2|Hilmi|user|user|user
3|jghgh|jhhj|hh|user
```

This is my code:

```py
def login():
    users = open("E:\\SI\\alpro\\Tubes\\users.txt").read().split("\n")
    for i in range(len(users)):
        users[i] = users[i].split("|")

    while True:
        print(">>> LOGIN")
        print("-"*100)
        username = str(input("Username \t: "))
        password = str(input("Password \t: "))

        for user in users:
            uname = user[2]
            pword = user[3]
            kode = user[4]

            if uname == username and pword == password and kode == "Administrator":
                print("\nWelcome, " + user[1] + ".")
                print("You Log in as : " + user[4] + ".")
                admin()
                break
            elif uname == username and pword == password and kode == "user":
                print("Welcome, " + user[1] + ".")
                print("You Log in as : " + user[4] + ".")
                break
            else:
                print("-"*58)
                print("| \u274c  \u274c  Invalid  \u274c  |\n")
                login()
        break
```

Comment: As a side note: it seems that you're storing passwords in plain text, [which is a bad practice](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120540/why-shouldnt-i-store-passwords-in-plaintext "Why shouldn't I store passwords in plaintext?").

Comment: Also, why are you calling `login()` when logging in fails if you already have a `while True` loop?

Answer (score 1):

If you add

```
print('checking', username , password, 'against', uname, pword, kode)
```

before the `if/elif/else`, you'll see the issue.
When you check "user"/"user" against your txt file, on the first round it is against admin. So it doesn't match, ends in the `else` clause, which immediately calls `login` again.

So you need to completely rethink the `while` and `if` blocks.
A nice idea could be with a users dictionary, so instead of all the `if user == username`, you'd directly get to the correct line with `user_dict[username]`.